# Create a sequence with with 2 level of variables

Tags: r, variables, levels

In the following code, I need to define PC in 2 levels (level 1= Id, level 2= Date). I need to do calculation for each Id on a different day separately. ( id 1 and 5 here in the dummy data set)

```
Shannon <- function(freq = rep(5, 5)) {
  freq <-freq[which(freq > 0)]           
  relfreq <- freq / sum(freq)           
  logNat <- log(relfreq)                 
  tempProd <- relfreq * logNat           
  shannon.index <- -sum(tempProd)        
  return(shannon.index)                  
}
Shannon(aggregate(count1$Count, list(count1$Species), sum)[, 2])

#dfname =counts

table <- c("Point", "Species", "Frequency","Shannon" )
for (i in 1:max(counts$Id)) {
  PC<- counts[counts$Id==i, ] 
  Rows <- c(i, nrow(PC), sum(PC$Count), Shannon(PC$Count))
  table <- rbind(table, Rows)
}
write.table (table,"table.tsv")
```

How do I calculate shannon with level 1 variable as Id and level 2 variable as Date?

Data:

| Id | Species | Date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 01-01-2021 | 3 |
| 1 | B | 01-01-2021 | 4 |
| 1 | B | 02-02-2021 | 2 |
| 2 | A | 02-01-2021 | 3 |
| 3 | A | 03-01-2021 | 3 |
| 3 | F | 03-01-2021 | 4 |
| 4 | C | 01-01-2021 | 1 |
| 5 | A | 06-01-2021 | 3 |
| 5 | D | 03-02-2021 | 7 |
| 6 | A | 01-01-2021 | 9 |
| 6 | B | 01-01-2021 | 3 |

Comment: Can you add your expected output?

Comment: I expect a a table, with point column as 1 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 (i.e. each point with different date is calculated differently) @AndreaM

Comment: Do you want group by date ?

Comment: @MohamedDesouky First level by id, then by date in second level

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df |> group_by(Id , Date) |> summarise(No_Species = sum(Count))
```

- output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
# Groups:   Id [6]
     Id Date       No_Species
  <int> <chr>           <int>
1     1 01-01-2021          3
2     1 02-02-2021          2
3     2 02-01-2021          3
4     3 03-01-2021          3
5     4 01-01-2021          1
6     5 03-02-2021          7
7     5 06-01-2021          3
8     6 01-01-2021         12
```

Comment: This works. Will there be any way that I can incorporate it within loop while defining i or PC . Because I have many other functions defined and calculate other outputs too. @MohamedDesouky

Comment: I can't decide unless i know the functions and outputs.

Comment: I have added the codes.. I think that will help. I need final table with some of the points repeated.